# How to make a KeyPath for NSSortDescriptor generic?

Tags: swift, generics, core-data, keypaths

I am a beginner to programming, so I'd appreciate a beginner-level explanation, if at all possible.

I'm doing Paul Hudson's 100 days of SwiftUI course and we are supposed to make the `keyPath` parameter for `NSSortDescriptor` generic. This is inside of a custom view that can be used inside another view to build a list with a Core Data fetch request. I hope that made sense. I can't figure out how to make `keyPath` generic, such that when I use this in another view I can pass in whatever keypath I want.

```
struct FilteredList<T: NSManagedObject, Content: View, V: Comparable>: View {
    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<T>
    var singers: FetchedResults<T> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }
    var ascendingOrNot: Bool
    var keyPath: KeyPath<T, V>

    let content: (T) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        List(singers, id: \.self) { singer in
            self.content(singer)
        }
    }

    init(filterKey: String, filterValue: String, keyPath: KeyPath<T, V>, ascendingOrNot: Bool, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (T) -> Content) {
        self.keyPath = keyPath
        self.ascendingOrNot = ascendingOrNot
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<T>(entity: T.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: keyPath, ascending: ascendingOrNot)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "%K BEGINSWITH %@", filterKey, filterValue))
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

I tried adding the generic type `V` and had it conform to `Comparable` but when I tried to use this in another view, I got the following error: Generic parameter 'V' could not be inferred.

Here is how the view is being used in `ContentView`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @State private var lastNameFilter = "A"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // list of matching singers
            FilteredList(filterKey: "lastName", filterValue: lastNameFilter, keyPath: \Singer.lastName, ascendingOrNot: true) { singer in
                Text("\(singer.wrappedLastName)")
            }

            Button("Add Examples") {
                let taylor = Singer(context: self.moc)
                taylor.firstName = "Taylor"
                taylor.lastName = "Swift"

                let ed = Singer(context: self.moc)
                ed.firstName = "Ed"
                ed.lastName = "Sheeran"

                let adele = Singer(context: self.moc)
                adele.firstName = "Adele"
                adele.lastName = "Adkins"

                try? self.moc.save()
            }

            Button("Show A") {
                self.lastNameFilter = "A"
            }

            Button("Show S") {
                self.lastNameFilter = "S"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `Singer` entity

```
extension Singer {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Singer> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Singer>(entityName: "Singer")
    }

    @NSManaged public var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged public var lastName: String?
    var wrappedFirstName: String {
        firstName ?? "Unknown"
    }
    var wrappedLastName: String {
        lastName ?? "Unknown"
    }
}
```

Any assistance is very much appreciated.

Comment: How did you "use this in another view"? Can you show the code?

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry about that. I just added it.

Comment: Is `Singer.lastName` a `String`? If so, then I cannot reproduce this error. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: @Sweeper I added the entity as well. Hopefully that allows you to reproduce the error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: String conforms to Comparable but String? (Optional) doesn’t

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you very much.